# Getting compile time error when converting Sybase Stored Procedure to Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Currently I am migrating Sybase Stored Procedure to Oracle. Once I migrated the SP in Oracle and debugging the SP, its throwing multiple syntax errors.

Currently I am stuck in one SP where I have a situation using one select statement after another.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1
(var1 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
  var2 IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL)
AS
BEGIN
  Select
      ( SELECT display_value
               FROM table1) AS COLONE,
             CASE a.someColumn
                 WHEN 0 THEN NULL
             ELSE CAST(CAST(a.someColumnAS VARCHAR2(8)) AS DATE)
                END someColumn,
             ( SELECT col1 
               FROM someTable
                WHERE TabCod = 'STATUS'
                        AND LinCod = a.col) COLTWO,
             ( SELECT DESCRIPTION 
               FROM table 
                WHERE column = CAST(a.col AS NUMBER(18))
                        AND inactive_dt IS NULL ) ColThree,
             ( SELECT LinVal 
               FROM table
                WHERE TabCod = 'EXTCOLTR'
                        AND LinCod = a.column) ColFour,
             a.SeqIdentifier ,
             c.NAME 
        FROM FirstTable a,
             SecondTable b,
             ThirdTable c
       WHERE a.CustAccount = var1
               AND a.SeqIdentifier = var2
               AND b.CustAccount = a.CustAccount
               AND b.SeqIdentifier = a.SeqIdentifier
               AND c.CustAccount = a.CustAccount
               AND c.SeqIdentifier = a.SeqIdentifier
        GROUP BY a.CustAccount,a.SeqIdentifier,a.Clo1,a.Col2,a.Col3,a.Col4,a.Col5,c.NAME;
END proc1;
```

I have resolved almost all the error except One error which is due to one select statement after another after the BEGIN.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You haven't included the error you get. You're missing a space before the `AS` in your first `cast()`, for a start, and both your arguments are called `var1`, but no idea what is coming from editing to hide you real table names etc. The error stack usually points to the line and character number where the error is - it isn't always helpful but it's a good place to start.

Comment: you have to select your query INTO something

Comment: the Error is Error(10,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored.

Comment: The original code is of company purpose that why i changed the codes. Security Reasons, sorry for this.

Comment: @ManishKumar is that a.col or a.column in ColFour? and pls fix that line "ELSE CAST(CAST(a.someColumnAS VARCHAR2(8)) AS DATE)" as Alex said, and pls remove that inline selects and put them in the FROM clause, (it's kindly overaged)

Comment: and what is that  "(SELECT display_value FROM table1) AS colone"  ? i think you have to fix the entire query, it's not good at all

Comment: @Thomas - that is a.ColumnName

Comment: @ManishKumar please edit the query in the question, because it has logical and semantical issues what need to be resolved before we can help

Comment: @ManishKumar - you get a a stack of errors, you've only shown the top one - it's the next one that will be more interesting. Please add the whole output you get from `show errors` to the question (not as a comment). But also make sure the changes you made when creating the question aren't introducing new problems - like that missing space. It's hard to tell what is really wrong and what is a typo made when posting.

Comment: You haven't posted the error messages. Plus you have posted a shonky  translation of the real code. So there's really not much we can do to help you.

Comment: Oh, and that "original code is of company purpose"? Looks like an entity-attribute-value implementation instead of a proper data model. Can see why they'd want to keep that secret :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints, please implement them

```
SELECT (SELECT display_value
          FROM table1) AS colone   --remove that select from here
      ,CASE a.somecolumn
         WHEN 0 THEN
          NULL
         ELSE
          CAST(CAST(a.somecolumnas VARCHAR2(8)) AS DATE)  -- fix that CAST
       END somecolumn
      ,(SELECT col1
          FROM sometable
         WHERE tabcod = 'STATUS'
           AND lincod = a.col) coltwo   --remove that select from here
      ,(SELECT description
          FROM TABLE
         WHERE column = CAST(a.col AS NUMBER(18))
           AND inactive_dt IS NULL) colthree    --remove that select from here 
      ,(SELECT linval
          FROM TABLE
         WHERE tabcod = 'EXTCOLTR'
           AND lincod = a.column) colfour   --remove that select from here
      ,a.seqidentifier
      ,c.name
  FROM firsttable  a
      ,secondtable b
      ,thirdtable  c
      --make joins for "table1", "sometable" and "TABLE"

 WHERE a.custaccount = var1
   AND a.seqidentifier = var2
   AND b.custaccount = a.custaccount
   AND b.seqidentifier = a.seqidentifier
   AND c.custaccount = a.custaccount
   AND c.seqidentifier = a.seqidentifier
 GROUP BY a.custaccount     --what is that group by here?
         ,a.seqidentifier
         ,a.clo1
         ,a.col2
         ,a.col3
         ,a.col4
         ,a.col5
         ,c.name
```

Comment: Nested selects are allowed in Oracle projections. So not sure how helpful these suggestions are.

Comment: they are allowed, but i dont think they are recommended... i have never seen yet a developer who used  , beacause it's lead to that --> "(SELECT display_value FROM table1) AS colone "  i dont think is allowed or valid